# I can not show two digit after dot like 0.3, 0.4

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit
func countDownToZero(num: Float) {
    print(num)
    if num < 1 {
        countDownToZero(num: num + 0.1)
    }
}
print("Countdown:")
countDownToZero(num: 0)
```

Output:

```
Countdown:
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.70000005
0.8000001
0.9000001
1.0000001
```

Comment: You should always use a `NumberFormatter` when presenting a number to users. In this case, set `maximumFractionDigits = 1` on it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: *"DOT is both a mathematical graph description language and a particular graph rendering engine (dot)"*. I've removed the incorrect tag. Please be more careful with the use of tags.

Comment: Thank you matt for great source! codo, I understand okay, but you fix my question toooo much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using the String initializer: String(format:)**

You can print the numbers by rounding the value to 1 decimal place using the below code:

```
print(String(format: "%.1f", num))
```

Suppose if you want to round the decimal places with a precision of 2 then you need to use the below code:

```
print(String(format: "%.2f", num))
```

**Using NumberFormatter()**

You can use NumberFormtter to make your outcome with 1 precision using the below code:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
let number = numberFormatter.string(from:num as NSNumber)!
print(number)
```

In the above code `string(from:)` method of `NumberFormatter()` expects an NSNumber so we need to bridge our integer in `num` by just adding `as NSNumber`

Comment: You should *really* use a number formatter instead of hard coded string formats

Comment: When you use a formatter, the results are localized. Not all locales use a `.` as the decimal separator.

Comment: @Alexander My mistake, after reading the question, I thought the post owner need to display 2 decimal places in the output. I have made changes to my answer for displaying the output with 1 decimal place and also included the **NumberFormatter()** way of solving the problem. 
Thanks.